# How to get daily percentage change of a stock(in array form) in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-finance

How can I fetch daily % change of a stock in google sheet e.g for last 30 days or last 1 year in array form?

So far I got the daily close prices like this.

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOGL", "close",DATE(2022,1,1),TODAY(),"DAILY")
```

Could someone please help?

Comment: I would like to confirm if you want the percentage change per day (in array form) for a month/year or the total percentage change given the duration?

Comment: @George percentage change per day (in array form) thanks

Answer (score 1):

### Suggestion:

You can try this formula that calculates the daily change percentage based on the result from your formula above.

### Formula:

```
=IFERROR(MAP(B1:B19,B2:B20, LAMBDA(old, new,((new-old)/old))),"--")
```

### Result:

The sample below calculates the percent change for the past `30 days` from today's date. You can adjust the date from your formula above based on how many days you want to show.

[image]

Notes:

- The `Percent` format is set on column C
- You can adjust the array parameter on the MAP formula `(B1:B19 and B2:B20)` if you intend to increase the number of days you want to show

Reference:

[MAP function](https://MAP%20function)

[Percent Change Formula](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/percentage-change.asp#:%7E:text=How%20Do%20I%20Calculate%20Percentage,multiply%20that%20number%20by%20100.)